# Search / and replace it with ; in xml tag with sublime text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, pcre

I am working on an .xml file with this tag

`<Categories><![CDATA[Test/Test1-Test2-Test3|Test4/Test5-Test6|Test7/Test8]]></Categories>`

and I am trying to replace `/` with `;` by using regular expressions in **Sublime Text 3**.

The output should be

`<Categories><![CDATA[Test;Test1-Test2-Test3|Test4;Test5-Test6|Test7;Test8]]></Categories>`

When I use this `(<Categories>\S+)\/(.+</Categories>)` it matches all the line and of course if I use this `\/` it matches all `/` everywhere inside the .xml file.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you example string, you could make use of a `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match and use `\K` to forget what has already been matched and then match a forward slash.

In the replacement use a `;`

Use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is `]]></Categories>`

```
(?:<Categories><!\[CDATA\[|\G(?!^))[^/]*\K/(?=[^][]*]]></Categories>)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `<Categories><!\[CDATA\[` Match `<Categories><![CDATA[`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^/]*` Match 0+ times not `/` using a negated character class
- `\K/` Forget what was matched, then match `/`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^][]*]]></Categories>` Match 0+ times not `[` or `]`, then match `]]></Categories>`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UKBZh9/1)